# resharper hotkey: subclasses that override certain method

Tags: resharper

Suppose I select some method and I want to open a tree in which I want to see all subclasses that override this method. What hotkey is used for this in Resharper? In Eclipse I use Ctrl+T for this operation as far as I remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've a virtual method in a base class and you want to see all the methods overriding it, set your cursor on the method and then select the following command: ReSharper | Navigate | Derived Symbols. This displays a list of methods that override the base class method. Now if you press the + key on the Numpad, the list will be shown in a tree window.

If you're using the Visual Studio keymap for R#, the shortcut key for the above mentioned menu command is Alt + End. You can also configure a custom shortcut for the ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoInheritors command in Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard.

PS. The same feature works when you want to list child classes of a base class.

Answer (score 0):

The Resharper command you are looking for is in the "Navigation & Search" category and it is called: resharper_gotoimplementation

According to the documentation the hotkey should be: Ctrl+Shift+Alt+B
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Implementation.html

However in my system this hotkey does not work. In this case you can add a keyboard mapping in Visual Studio for the resharper_gotoimplementation command. You can do this in Tools -> Options -> Keyboard.